# Why modifying the weights of a recurrent neural network in MATLAB does not cause the output to change when predicting on same data?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, regression, recurrent-neural-network

I consider the following recurrent neural network (RNN):

[RNN under consideration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNjB5.png)

where **x** is the input (a vector of reals), **h** the hidden state vector and **y** is the output vector. I trained the network on Matlab using some data **x** and obtained W, V, and U.

However, in MATLAB after changing matrix W to W', and keeping U,V the same, the output (**y**) of the RNN that uses W is the same as the output (**y'**) of the RNN that uses W' when both predict on the same data **x**. Those two outputs should be different just by looking at the above equation, but I don't seem to be able to do that in MATLAB (when I modify V or U, the outputs do change). How could I fix the code so that the outputs (**y**) and (**y'**) are different as they should be?

The relevant code is shown below:

```
[x,t] = simplefit_dataset;  % x: input data ; t: targets
net = newelm(x,t,5);  % Recurrent neural net with 1 hidden layer (5 nodes) and 1 output layer (1 node)
net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'tansig'; % 'tansig': equivalent to tanh and also is the activation function used for hidden layer 
net.biasConnect = [0;0]; % biases set to zero for easier experimenting 
net.derivFcn ='defaultderiv'; % defaultderiv: tells Matlab to pick whatever derivative scheme works best for this net
view(net) % displays the network topology
net = train(net,x,t); % trains the network
W = net.LW{1,1}; U = net.IW{1,1}; V = net.LW{2,1}; % network matrices

Y = net(x); % Y: output when predicting on data x using W

net.LW{1,1} = rand(5,5); % This is the modified matrix W, W'
Y_prime = net(x) % Y_prime: output when predicting on data x using W'

max(abs(Y-Y_prime )); % The difference between the two outputs is 0 when it probably shouldn't be.
```

Edit: minor corrections.

Answer (score 2):

[image: network view]

This is the recursion in your first layer: (from the docs)

> The weight matrix for the weight going to the ith layer from the jth
>   layer (or a null matrix [ ]) is located at net.LW{i,j} if
>   net.layerConnect(i,j) is 1 (or 0).

So `net.LW{1,1}` are the weights to the first layer from the first layer (i.e. recursion), whereas `net.LW{2,1}` stores the weights to the second layer from the first layer. Now, what does it mean when one can change the weights of the recursion randomly without any effect (in fact, you can set them to zero `net.LW{1,1} = zeros(size(W));` without an effect). Note that this essentially is the same as if you drop the recursion and create as simple feed-forward network:
[image: feedforward network]

Hypothesis: **The recursion has no effect.**

You will note that if you change the weights to the second layer (1 neuron) from the first layer (5 neurons) `net.LW{2,1} = zeros(size(V));`, it will affect your prediction (the same is of course true if you change the input weights `net.IW`).

**Why does the recursion has no effect?**
Well, that beats me. I have no idea where this special glitch is or what the theory is behind the `newelm` network.